# OnClick in a CardView <include> layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, include, cardview

I have a xml that contains some `CardView` `<include>`, I want to set `onClick` in the `CardView` includes to open an `Activity` in my project. I tried to set the `onClick` in the `CardView` layout as you will see in the code below, it opens normally but triggers an error sometimes and the application stops. How can I set the `onClick` in this include?

This is the `<include>` in my xml

```
 <include layout="@layout/view_caderno"
            android:id="@+id/view_caderno" />
```

and here is the **CardView**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="15dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:onClick="Caderno"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/note"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pic1"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Diário"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/baby2"
        android:text="@string/diário"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Paste error log and code of Caderno function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make OnClickListener programmatically :

```
       CardView yourCardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.view_caderno);

        yourCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do what you want on click event
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this answer - [stackoverflow.com/a/37790333/1333022](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37790333/1333022)

Dynamically you can add layout in your cardview.